# Set and access dynamic class property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm converting some ES6 code to TypeScript and I noticed that I had an `Api` class that was importing an object containing several API resources all extending a common `ApiResource` class.

The `Api` class takes all the keys and values defined in the object and sets them in the instance `Api`.

So, for example let say the following is the object containing the different resources:

```
import Companies from './Resources/Companies';
import Users .   from './Resources/Users';

export default {
    Companies,
    Users
}

// Resources.js
```

At this point the `Api` class would import `Resources` and create a new `Api` instance:

```
import AppResources from './Resoruces';

import Users from './Internal/Users.js';

const internalResources = {
    Users
};

export default class Api
{
    constructor()
    {
        let resources = {...internalResources, ...AppResources};

        for (let key in availableAPIResources) {
            this[key] = new availableAPIResources[key];
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Now, by simply instantiating `Api` I can easily access both `Users` and `Companies`:

```
let api = new Api;
api.Users.get();
api.Companies.get();
```

The problem is that, because of the TypeScript types, I can't do this anymore unless I start using `any` everywhere but that's something I would like to avoid.

## What would be an alternative to my previous pattern in TypeScript?

Keep in mind that the list of resources may vary and it's not possible for me to know it before compilation (hence dynamic).

Comment: TypeScript is really about static typing and what you want is the contrary, so I don't see how you could conciliate the two... Or maybe a solution would be to write a code generator?

Comment: Not sure where the dynamic part is.. The `Api` class takes a hard dependency on a specific module that exports a specific object...

Comment: I need to add the resources to the `Api` class based on the content of the `Resources` object, so it's not something that I can just define on the `Api` class.

Comment: Ok, but that is not fully dynamic, it's more static based on the content of another object.. Which we can model with Typescript pretty well with napped types

Comment: If you really can't know the scope of possible types at compile time, then you're unfortunately out of luck - by Typescript's very nature, only compile-time information is available for type checking. If, however, there's some range of possible types that could be available, you can probably accomplish what you want using generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading (a second time) through the [TypeScript Advanced Types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) I realized that  I can simply create a new type

```
type ApiType = {
    [P in keyof (typeof internalResources & typeof AppResources)]
        : (typeof internalResources & typeof AppResources)[P];
};
```

and use it where needed.